# Could not install package - Package target the same as project's settings

Tags: c#, android, facebook, mobile, xamarin.android

I'm working on an Android project in Xamarin for Visual Studio.
I'm getting an error whereby the Xamarin.Facebook.Android SDK targets the 5.1 framework, which is what my 
Target Framework(Compile using), Target Android version and Minimum Android version are all set to(Have tried different variants of higher and lower).

The package in question has a dependency of Android V7, which I have installed.
Have an added an image for good measure.
This is a fresh project, and i've tried rebuilding the solution after any trial-and-error changes to the project's properties.

Screenshot: https://ibb.co/jOtfKk

Is this a bug, or has someone else encountered this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Created another project and it miraculously worked this time.
Man I hate the VS, C# and Xamarin world.